Multiple date recognition formula
I am trying to simplify a formula that recognizes dates along a timeline, that fall within start and end dates as inputs. The current working formula is:
=OR(AND(H$1>=$A2,H$1<=$B2),AND(H$1>=$C2,H$1<=$D2),AND(H$1>=$E2,H$1<=$F2)).
Is there a way to reduce redundancy in the string, that would be able to recognize more or less start + end dates as inputs?
In the graphic below, the inputs are in cells A2:F2, and the outputs are in cells H2:AA2.


what would simplify mean?  To me that is the simplest version of that formula.  Can you expand what you want?

If you have three time frames and want to compare a single date againts each of the three time frames, that looks like the most simple formula to achieve that.

Are you looking for something like this, bit shorter than yours : =OR((H$1>=VSTACK($A2,$C2,$E2))*(H$1<=VSTACK($B2,$D2,$F2)))

or longer but allows full ranges: =LET(_dts,$A2:$F2,_tgt,H$1:AA$1,_arr,WRAPROWS(_dts,2),REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_arr)),LAMBDA(_z,_y,_z+(INDEX(_arr,_y,1)<=_tgt)*(INDEX(_arr,_y,2)>=_tgt)*(INDEX(_arr,_y,1)<>"")*(INDEX(_arr,_y,2)<>""))))>0

For entire range: =BYCOL(H1:AA1,LAMBDA(x,OR((x>=VSTACK(A2,C2,E2))*(x<=VSTACK(B2,D2,F2)))))

Did you consider writing a function =Between(a; b; c), which checks if a is between b and c? That would turn your formula into =AND(Between(H$1;$A2;$B2);...?

Try either
=OR(BYROW(WRAPROWS($A2:$F2,2), LAMBDA(_r,H$1=MEDIAN(H$1,_r))))

, or
=LET(Target, H$1, Dates, $A2:$F2, 
    OR(BYROW(WRAPROWS(Dates, 2), LAMBDA(_r, Target=MEDIAN(Target, _r))))
 )

(if you only want to define the target once)
This will convert your date range into a 2-column list of paired start/end dates (with WRAPROWS), then step through each pair in turn (with BYROW) and check if the target date is between the start/end dates, inclusive (using MEDIAN), and runs an OR across the results
You can even turn it into a LAMBDA function in your Defined Names for the workbook:
=LAMBDA(Target, Dates, OR(BYROW(WRAPROWS(Dates, 2), LAMBDA(_r, Target=MEDIAN(Target, _r)))))

